# Event listener firing numerous time

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which is firing Event a lot of times and I want it to fire one time each time the modal appears, the gist of the code is to wait for Modal to be a part of DOM after which I run the function hence setTimeout to override the Modal classes. After which I have Event which is firing numerous times.

If I use clearInterval, my CSS isn't applied

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (document.querySelector('[data-test-id="modal"]')) {
    poller(['[data-test-id="modal"]'], () => {
      let msgNode = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="AvailabilityMessagesstyled__"]');
      [...msgNode].forEach((delivery) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (delivery.children[0].innerText.indexOf("Available") !== -1 ||
            delivery.children[0].innerText.indexOf("available") !== -1) {
            delivery.children[0].classList.add("TP")
          }
          if (delivery.children[0].innerText.indexOf("Unavailable") !== -1) {
            delivery.children[0].classList.add("TP__red")
          }
        }, 200)
        // qty
        let qtyCounter = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-id="qty-selector"]'));
        console.log(qtyCounter);
        [...qtyCounter].forEach((counter) => {
          counter.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('clicked')
          })
        })
      });
    })
  }
}, 2000)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding a click handler at every interval. You should probably be doing that _outside_ the interval function.

Comment: Do you realize that "available" is in the text "Unavailable" so it will always match.

Comment: @epascarello I thought it will match first match item in given string. No?

Comment: `console.log("Unavailable".indexOf("available"))`

Comment: @epascarello what do u recommend to use?

Comment: regular expression? Exact match? Really depends on what your are matching against.  `"Unavailable".match(/\bavailable\b/i);`  and`"Unavailable".match(/\bunavailable\b/i);`